# How can I get the website Id's a product is associated with?

Tags: magento-1.7, product

I can set the website ids against a product by adding `'websites' => array(1,2)` to an array and saving the product. The problem is this overwrites all websites so if I only want to add a product to a website (without touching the rest) then I need to know which websites the product is associated with.

I tried `$product->getWebsites()` but `websites` isn't in the `_data` var of the product object so returns null.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$product->getWebsiteIds()
```

should get you what you need.