# Magento 1: How can we get WebsiteId or websites from $product?

Tags: magento-1.9

Magento 1: How can we get WebsiteId or websites array from $product?

Something like?

```
$product->getWebsiteId()
```

[image]

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7371/how-can-i-get-the-website-ids-a-product-is-associated-with

Comment: Marked as DUPE ... sorry

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the website Id's a product is associated with?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7371/how-can-i-get-the-website-ids-a-product-is-associated-with)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the product object if not loaded, then use this code.

```
$product->getWebsiteIds() ;
```

It will give you that data which you want.